# Should I increase the number of wraps around tuning peg if tuning down

Tags: guitar, tuning, alternative-tunings

I used this method for stringing my guitar:

https://www.taylorguitars.com/support/strings/changing-steel-strings

Which states:
"Two to three wraps is perfect for the bass strings."

If I were to tune to Drop D sometimes and Standard E other times do I still wrap the same amount of times when tuned to E and not worry about the drop D. Or wrap the same number of timeswhen tuned to D and have extra wraps when tuned to E. 
How about E flat (nirvana style)?

Comment: The difference between the tunings would not be a whole wind, so really the point is moot.

Comment: @tetsujin why not an answer?

Comment: It felt a tad short of actually doing some research to prove my point, tbh ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It's not so much the tuning, it's the gauge of the string that matters. The lower the gauge (i.e., thin strings) the more wraps you need. Fat strings have less of a tendency to slip or rub against the peg's string hole (where breaks often happen).

If you're tuning down, you might get better tone if you switch strings, in which case you can wrap your strings less. To be honest, the amount of times you wrap isn't that big of a deal.

Answer (score 2):

It's hardly an issue. Two or even three full wraps on the barrel of the machine head is enough, particularly on the wound strings. By then, the string isn't going to slip - and even if it did, an extra part-turn will save it - so tuning from E to D isn't going to be a problem. Each guitar is subtly different, but generalising, it's no big deal. If you're really concerned, an extra turn won't hurt, anyway. Might be a time to consider another guitar to go with the original, one standard, the other as you like it.

Comment: The only other things I'd add would be, wind neatly, down towards the head, each wind touching but not overlapping the previous one, never overlap or cross-wind. Stop before you hit the ferrule.